# PyTorch custom loss function with sklearn confusion matrix

Tags: scikit-learn, pytorch, loss-function, confusion-matrix

I would like to use the following loss function as the PyTorch loss function, which quantifies the misclassifications (weighted average) for each class in the confusion matrix:

```
def loss_fcn(outputs, labels):
    from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

    def Error_class(Res):
        Error=[]
        for i,ires in enumerate(Res):
            ierror=[]
            for ii,r in enumerate(ires):
                weight=torch.abs(i-ii)
                error=weight*r
                ierror.append(error)
            Error.append(ierror)

        Error_Res=[]
        for ierror,ires in zip(Error,Res):
            err=torch.sum(ierror)/torch.sum(ires)
            Error_Res.append(err)
        all_err=torch.sum([ torch.sum(x) for x in Error])/torch.sum([ torch.sum(x) for x in Res])

        return Error_Res

    return torch.mean(Error_class(confusion_matrix(labels.numpy(), outputs.numpy())))
```

However I always got the following runtime error for the return command:

*"RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Variable that requires grad. Use var.detach().numpy() instead."*

I have tried changing the return command to be:

```
return torch.mean(Error_class(confusion_matrix(labels.detach().numpy(), outputs.detach().numpy())))
```

which yields a different error:

*"Classification matrices can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets."*

I am quite confused as to where I should insert .detach().numpy(). Could somebody teach me how to make confusion matrix amenable to grad? Thanks!

Comment: The last line where you call `outputs.numpy()`, why can't you call `outputs.detach().numpy()` like the error message is telling you to?

Comment: @jhso It does not work, the error becomes "Classification matrices can't handle a mix of multiclass and continuous-multioutput targets".

Comment: Please update the question with the new information.